# setting manage.py to executable is not working

Tags: django, zsh, chmod

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on django.

In the directory where `manage.py` is located I've run the following command in iTerm to set the file to execute: `chmod +x manage.py`

However when I type in `manage.py startapp greetings` and hit return, I get the following error:
`zsh: command not found: manage.py`

But when I run `ls -l`, it shows what I believe to be the correct permissions:
`-rwxr-xr-x`

Also, if I enter `./manage.py` I get this error:
`zsh: permission denied: ./manage.py`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a full output of ``ls -l | grep manage.py``? Maybe something wrong with the file owner

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x   1 ryentzer  staff  253 Apr 18 23:22 manage.py

Comment: just to be sure, in the terminal type `pwd` to check if you're in the right directory

Comment: `pwd` shows that I'm in the right directory. I can set the permissions on the file to 777, see that the permissions have been set but when I try to run the file it still says "command not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use:

```
python manage.py <cmd>
```

Comment: Not sure why someone has given this a down vote. python manage.py can indeed be used here (even though it may not be the 'normal' way of doing things)

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between `startapp`.

Also you need to make `manage.py` executable to execute it. Do `chmod +x manage.py` to make it executable. Alternatively you can do `python manage.py <cmd>` instead.

Comment: I fixed the space between `startapp` in the question. I was not doing that in the terminal. Also, I was setting the file to execute, that's the reason for the question because it's not working. Thanks.

Comment: just try setting permission to '-rw-------'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the first line in manage.py is `#!/usr/bin/env python` so that the shell will now that it needs to execute this file using Python. Read more... [Shebang (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)